# Does authorship markup interfere with Google rich snippets?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-authorship

We are currently supporting a website where we have successfully added rich snippets on the product pages and they show up properly on Google search results.

What happens when Authorship has been added to the website? Will they interfere with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they won't interfere with each other my opinion. You can use both rich snippets as well as Authorship for your website. 
Refer the below image and post for more info..

http://d2v4zi8pl64nxt.cloudfront.net/1340490160_0bac471144bfbcedcf202a49ac33ad68.jpg

http://moz.com/blog/read-but-learn-by-doing-an-approach-to-the-analysis-of-seo-issues-between-authorship-google-plus-and-snippets

Comment: So if we originally show the product image for the rich snippets, the author picture won't replace it?

Comment: http://d2v4zi8pl64nxt.cloudfront.net/1340490160_0bac471144bfbcedcf202a49ac33ad68.jpg in this image it shows google result with mixture of Youtube rich snippets and Authorship. Thats why i told its possible. I found this on http://moz.com/blog/read-but-learn-by-doing-an-approach-to-the-analysis-of-seo-issues-between-authorship-google-plus-and-snippets

Comment: Fantastic find, thanks! You may want to add the link/images to your original answer to improve it.

Comment: You are welcome rikitikitik..